# Exporting a prototype in node.js: module.exports=Prototype or exports.Prototype=Prototype?

Tags: node.js, module, export, prototype, require

What is the preferred way to export a prototype in node.js? You can take two approaches:

1. Export the prototype itself

   ```
   function A () {
   }
   module.exports = A;
   ```

   which is used as:

   ```
   var A = require('./A.js');
   var a = new A();
   ```
2. Export an object containing the prototype as property

   ```
   function A () {
   }
   exports.A = A;
   ```

   which is used as:

   ```
   var A = require('./A.js').A;
   var p = new A();
   ```

The first solution looks much more convenient to me, though I know there are concerns about replacing the exports object. Which of the two is best to use and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one would only be useful if you exported multiple classes from one file which is something that is questionable by itself.

There is no problem in replacing the exports object at all.

Comment: Ok thanks. Replacing the exports object can give issues when having circular references - but if that is the case you should be careful what you do anyway.